# How can a .net web developer develop a mobile app?

Tags: html, cordova, mobile

I am a .net web developer right now.
However,i would like to develop some mobile app.

Without mono,
could any other way help me do this?

Could html5+css3+jqmobile work?
I really do not know how could a web app works as a client on mobile phone.

I get some information about phonegap.
Could this make web app work as a client(without java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap will package your html5+css3+jqmobile to run as a **native app** in a mobile device. To answer your question, yes this will work without **java** but with **javascript**.